# Set splash screen and app icon in appery.io + cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, appery.io

I am developing a cordova app with **appery.io**. I don't know how to build for android and iOS with splash screen and app icon(Change splash screen and app icon). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open App settings under Project when you have the app open in your browser.

Then click on Android binary and then you can select / upload an icon.

The launch images section (read Splash Screen) is on the same page, where you can upload / select a different image.

Once uploaded you will need to export the app to a Binary (.apk) file, which is under the EXPORT menu at the top.  That will give you a QR code to download the file to your device.

Once installed you will see the icon and when you load the app you should see the launch image / splash screen.